# Wxpython cut copy paste and openfiledialog

Tags: python, events, dialog, wxpython, openfiledialog

i have a web browser made in python with menu.
in one menu i have cut copy paste but no functionality and i need to make them work. i need an example of class oncopy.(event menu)

Open file i manage to work like this .takes file and print on screen the link to that file but how can make open dialog to open a file at least one type of file?

Comment: Marius, maybe you are a fair noob, so please explain better this and another questions you asked today. Otherwise this could be considered spam and I will flag/donwvote it accordingly

Comment: Marius, about copy/paste, what do you want to copy, a piece of text you select in the HTML window? the full page?. Please check wxpython demo application (download from wxpython site "wxpython docs and demos" application) and search for examples of wx.HtmlWindow and of ActiveX_IEHtmlWindow.

Comment: copy/paste for a piece of text from html window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `filepath` is the absolute pathname of the file you got from the opendialog, try:

```
import os
os.startfile(filepath)
```

This will open your file with its corresponding windows application to which its extension is associated (like clicking twice in the file icon)

To copy a selected text in the HTML window, if you used:

```
import wx.lib.iewin as iewin
```

then in your Frame or Panel subclass you create your instance of the browser object in the `__init__()` method with:

```
self.ie = iewin.IEHtmlWindow(self, -1, style =wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
```

and bind the copy button onclick event with an 'on_copy' method.
Finally, you define the on_copy(self, event) method that should be triggered when you click the 'copy' button:

```
def on_copy(self, event):
   self.selection = self.ie.GetStringSelection(asHTML=False)
```